# std::format of user-defined types?

Tags: c++, c++20, fmt

In C++20 - how do you make a user-defined type compatible with `std::format`?

For example, let's say I have a type called `Point`:

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

with its `operator<<` defined:

```
inline std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& o, Point pt)
{ return o << "[" << pt.x << << ", " << pt.y << "]"; }
```

then will the following program output `Hello [3, 4]!`?

```
int main() {
   Point pt{3,4};
   std::cout << std::format("Hello {}!\n", pt);
}
```

If yes - why and how?

If no - what do I have to add to the definition of `Point` to to make it work?

Comment: You should overload `std::formatter<Ti, CharT>`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`std::format` doesn't support `operator<<`, you need to provide a [`formatter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter) specialization for your type (`Point`) instead. The easiest way to do it is by reusing one of existing formatters, e.g. `std::formatter<std::string>`:

```cpp
template <>
struct std::formatter<Point> : std::formatter<std::string> {
  auto format(Point p, format_context& ctx) const {
    return formatter<string>::format(
      std::format("[{}, {}]", p.x, p.y), ctx);
  }
};
```

This will give you all format specifications supported by `std::string` out of the box. Here is an example of formatting `Point` with center alignment padded with '~' to 10 characters:

```
auto s = std::format("{:~^10}", Point{1, 2});
// s == "~~[1, 2]~~"
```

which is nontrivial to achieve with iostreams.

Comment: If there is no `std::formatter` for a given type then why didn't we define that `std::format` falls back to the `operator<<` if one is available?

Comment: Fall back on `operator<<` introduces a lot of problems, for example, output depending on visibility of `formatter` specialization and even potentially ODR violations. This is why it was not included in `std::format`.

Comment: Note that https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format currently claims _"... and reuse some of [I/O streams] infrastructure such as overloaded insertion operators for user-defined types."_ which is inconsistent with this answer.

Comment: cppreference is wrong in this case, std::format has its own extension mechanism and doesn't use operator<<.

Comment: Note that the incorrect statement regarding `format` and `operator<<` has been removed from cppreference.

Comment: Which compilers support `std::format`? I tried this solution in Compiler Explorer [here](https://godbolt.org/z/18vdqoGdb) with no luck.

Comment: std::format is purely library, not compiler, feature and it's supported in the most recent version of libc++ and partially in libstdc++. I am not sure if either is available on CE yet.

Comment: I assume "x86-64 gcc (trunk)" on CE will have been built in the last few days, including libstdc++. I wonder if a trunk build of libc++ is available online.

Answer (score 8):

You have to specialize [`std::formatter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter) for your type.

```
namespace std
{
    template<class CharT>
    struct formatter<Point, CharT>
    {  
        template <typename FormatParseContext>
        auto parse(FormatParseContext& pc)
        {
            // parse formatter args like padding, precision if you support it
            return pc.end(); // returns the iterator to the last parsed character in the format string, in this case we just swallow everything
        }

        template<typename FormatContext>
        auto format(Point p, FormatContext& fc) 
        {
            return std::format_to(fc.out(), "[{}, {}]", p.x, p.y);
        }
    };
}
```

I don't think the ostream operator will work but I have no sources to support this claim.

Comment: Isn't _partial_ specialization of standard types undefined behavior?

Comment: @StaceyGirl I don't think so. Quote from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std): _"It is allowed to add template specializations for any standard library [...] template to the namespace std only if the declaration depends on at least one program-defined type [...]"_

Comment: You are right, ostream operator<< is not supported.

Comment: @vitaut Oh mr. format himself to the rescue. Thanks for the edit. Wasn't sure from what was written on cppreference.