# Inserting Characters in Placeholder in `std::format`

Tags: c++, c++20, stdformat

In the C++20 `<format>` library, is it possible to insert characters in a placeholder, so that those characters behave like a part of the passed parameter?

For example, I have the following statement:

```
std::format("Test '{:<{}}'", 123, 5)
```

which produces `Test '123  '`.

What I need it to produce is `Test '123; '` (note the semicolon after `123` is left-justified together with `123`).

In other words, is there a shorter alternative to this?

```
std::format("Test '{:<{}}'\n", std::format("{};", 123), 5)
```

Comment: seems like a duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909102/stdformat-of-user-defined-types

Comment: I don't think so. My question is not about user-defined types.

Comment: However user-defined type with corresponding formatter seems to be a solution to your problem.

Comment: user7860670, thank you for commenting! Based on your comment, the answer to my question is "*No, it's not possible.*". Thus, in my case, double `std::format` looks prettier. Else, I'd have to add tons of code for different UDT's.

Comment: As far as I know, about the only way to do this would be to convert to a string first, add the semicolon, then justify the resulting string.

Comment: @KamilCuk, `123` is just an example. It may be a variable and, therefore, I need more flexible solution than hardcoding every possible value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In other words, is there a shorter alternative to this?

No.